# Problems Parsing JSON from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, json

I get a response form my server via AJAX with an array that is json_encode (php funciton). However, I am having difficulty parsing it.

I can do this:

```
alert(response);
```

But it just gives me a bunch of text like so:

[{"user_id":"Dev_V2_MEH_0910_M03_v03c_NEW_CODE_03"......"grouper_opae_algorithm":"nap_v42lp"}]

Please note, I cut out a lot. I have tried this:

```
alert(response[0].user_id);
```

That just gives me undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting it back as a string - you need to convert it into an object.

If you're using a library like jQuery or Prototype then there will be a built-in method to do this. Otherwise you can use eval:

```
object = eval('(' + response + ')');
```

This does open some security holes though - if a function was injected into the JSON it would be executed.

Comment: What if I am using JQuery. Is it getJson()?

Comment: Yes you should use the getJSON() method: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON

Comment: ...and you need another single quote. (:

Answer (score 1):

The most basic way to parse JSON is with the eval() command:

```
json = eval(response);
alert(json[0].user_id);
```

It's better to use libraries like Prototype or jQuery to help sanitize your JSON if the source is untrusted.

Comment: Source is trusted its my own server, but I prefer to use JQuery. Is it the getJSon() function?

Comment: You need brackets around the response

Answer (score 0):

You can also [download](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) the [official JSON parser](http://json.org/js.html) for javascript, which would let you do:

```
var myObj = JSON.parse(respsonse);
```

Answer (score 0):

Crockford doesn't recommend the eval() function.

http://json.org/js.html

You could use his json parse/stringify function instead

http://json.org/json2.js